# SQLSyntaxErrorException for executing native SQL IN clause query in Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I am using MySql Database. I like to write a native query on 'tbl_users'. I wrote the query like below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users AS u WHERE u.id IN (:ids)")
List<User> findByUserIdIn(@Param("ids") Set<Long> ids);
```

But my spring application thrown an exception like

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')'
```

What will be the right query or how can I overcome this problem. Pls help.

Comment: Are you sending empty list or null in `ids`? `()` is not needed actually in query.

Comment: @Rono: list contains id values, so not empty or null.

Comment: No need to create custom `findByUserIdIn` method. `JpaRepository` already contains `findAllById` : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: Can't reproduce. Alternatively you can use `findByIdIn` method naming query